# Find entity that has related entities with given primary keys

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

I have the following entities:

```
Chat
id: uuid // PK
```

```
ChatMember
chatId: uuid // PK
userId: uuid // PK
```

Chat entity relates to ChatMember entity as one to many

I want to find chat that has chat members with specific userIds (by two different userIds for example. Chat must have two members with given userIds)

Comment: I would strongly model the first table as two tables with 1:N relationship between them. Avoid using arrays.

Comment: @TheImpaler Chat table relates to ChatMember as one to many. It's just code-like model view